# Excel Multi Dependant Dropdowns Based on repeating data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dropdown, primeng-dropdowns

Am looking to create a multi layer dropdown solution for selecting addresses, where the dropdowns options change based on prior selections.

E.g - Selection options are Region, Country, City, Address Line 1

The ask is that if someone selects Region EMEA, the country list should show only countries in EMEA. They then select a country and the city lists only those pertaining to that country.

The issue I think may be how the source data is structured, but hoping there may be a solution without have to alter the source information. If that's not possible, then any solution that works is great.

Preferably this will not use VBA. It can be used initially to structure the data, but not for the dropdowns to operate in use as the file will uploaded to Excel Online.

The structure of the address data is as follows as an example:

| REGION | COUNTRY | CITY | ADDRESS LINE 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APAC | Australia | Adelaide | 12 Fairview Road |
| APAC | New Zealand | Auckland | 1313 Cambridge Drive |
| EMEA | UK | London | 24 Sycamore Street |
| EMEA | UK | London | 25 Madison Avenue |
| EMEA | Spain | Madrid | 567 Mulberry Street |
| APAC | New Zealand | Auckland | 2345 George Street |
| APAC | India | Dehli | 322 Locust Street |
| APAC | India | Dehli | 12 Beech Street |
| APAC | India | Punjab | 55 Route 7 |
| LATAM | Brazil | Sao Paulo | 7 Arch Street |

Comment: There are several examples on YouTube.  What have you tried?  Search [Excel dependent drop downs](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=excel+dependent+drop+downs)

Comment: Hi @TinMan - yes I did look on YouTube first, but none of the example seem to cater to data structured in this manor. Also, not wanting duplications to show for Country India for example

Comment: Explore: [Excel Dynamic Arrays: Data Validation List Dropdown: Unique, Sorted & No Blanks EMT 1523](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYgFRe1WGEM)

Comment: Thanks, this would work. Only issue is that these dropdowns need to be placed in a table where multiple lines can be filled in. All the examples are based on a single row selection. So need it to be dynamic based on the region select in a specific cell. E.g - A2 = APAC, so B2 shows APAC countries only. Then A3 = EMEA, so B3 show EMEA countries. This is where i'm becoming stuck